# SVN rename all files in directory using regular expression

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can I rename all files in a directory in TortoiseSVN using a regular expression?

Basically I want to strip out the last two characters of the file name before the .extension.

For example,

```
MyFileXY.c 
MyOtherFile12.c
```

changed to:

```
MyFile.c
MyOtherFile.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in Tortoise itself, but you can in various shell scripts using the command line version of Subversion client. In Shell, it'd be ***something*** like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ find . \( -name ".svn" -prune -false \) -o -type f | while read file
  do
      newFile=${file%??}
      svn mv $file $newFile
  done
```

You can do something similar using PowerShell which is now included on most Windows platforms (although you might have to install .NET first). I'd give you that syntax except I really don't know Powershell.

This is one of the reasons I tell people to learn the Subversion command line. It can greatly extend the powers of Subversion to do tasks like this.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Syntax is given on an **as is** basis and there is no implicit guarantee that it's correct. User assumes all responsibilities for running said syntax. All decisions by the judges are final. Offer void where prohibited by law.*

Comment: If I don't have Subversion can I install it with the current existing TortoiseSVN client I have installed?

Comment: If you have TortoiseSVN 1.7 you already have the Subversion command line utilities--so you do not have to install anything. Just check the bin directory under TortoiseSVN. Also note that David's script (i.e. the `find` command) is for Linux/Unix, not for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @DavidW's answer, here is the basic PowerShell sequence to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem . | % { svn mv $_.name ( $_.name -replace '..\.','.' ) }
```

This will work for the particular samples in the question but it will fail in the corner case where a filename contains multiple dots, e.g. something like "ProjectX.MyFileXY.c". Either of the two regular expressions below are more robust and will handle multiple dots (this also shows how to quickly test a regular expression/replace operation in isolation):

```
"ProjectX.MyFileXY.c" -replace '..\.(?=[^.]*$)','.'
"ProjectX.MyFileXY.c" -replace '..(\.[^.]*?)$','$1'
```

Though the question only asked for handling files in the *current* directory, David included handling descendants so I thought I should generalize my solution as well for parallelism.
The general solution--examining the subtree rooted in the current directory--requires adding just a couple parameters to Get-ChildItem (I have also swapped in one of the more robust regexs here):

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -NoContainer |
    % { svn mv $_.name ( $_.name -replace '..\.(?=[^.]*$)','.' ) }
```

But this does *not* prune private `.svn` directories as David has done with the Linux `find` command. Because `Get-ChildItem` has no such option, I added an enhanced version ([Get-EnhancedChildItem](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/api/powershell/CleanCode/EnhancedChildItem/Get-EnhancedChildItem.html)) to my open source libraries (download [here](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/download.html)) that includes a few additional parameters; `-ExcludeTree` is equivalent to `-prune`:

```
Get-EnhancedChildItem . -ExcludeTree .svn -Recurse -NoContainer |
    % { svn mv $_.name ( $_.name -replace '..\.(?=[^.]*$)','.' ) }
```

Finally, my enhanced cmdlet offers even one further option (`-Svn`) that may be used to not just ignore Subversion's private directory but rather to ignore *any* files that are not under Subversion source control:

```
Get-EnhancedChildItem . -Svn -Recurse -NoContainer |
    % { svn mv $_.name ( $_.name -replace '..\.(?=[^.]*$)','.' ) }
```

Comment: Thanks. I would have done a PowerShell answer, but I just started learning it last Thursday and will probably use it for this single job and never use it again. It's definitely better than the CMD shell's syntax, but I'd rather use Python or Perl.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I rename all files in a directory in TortoiseSVN using a regular
>   expression?

No. SRC and DST in `svn move` are **string constants**

If *your shell* can perform such trimming, you can *try to use* results inside svn commands, but anyway - it is not SVN part of game